# Can you chain methods by returning a pointer to their object?

Tags: c++, class-design

My goal is to allow chaining of methods such as:

```
class Foo;
Foo f;
f.setX(12).setY(90);
```

Is it possible for `Foo`'s methods to return a pointer to their instance, allowing such chaining?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For that specific syntax you'd have to return a reference

```
class Foo {
public:

  Foo& SetX(int x) {
    /* whatever */
    return *this;
  } 

  Foo& SetY(int y) {
    /* whatever */
    return *this;
  } 
};
```

P.S. Or you can return a copy (`Foo` instead of `Foo&`). There's no way to say what you need without more details, but judging by the function name (`Set...`) you used in your example you probably need a reference return type.

Answer (score 4):

Another example is the [Named Parameter Idiom](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.18).

Answer (score 3):

Yes its possible. A comon example is operator overloading, such as operator+=().

For example, if you have a class called ComplexNumber, and want to do something such as a+=b, then you could

```
ComplexNumber& operator+=(ComplexNumber& other){
     //add here
     return *this; 
}
```

In your case you could use.

```
Foo& setX(int x){
//yada yada yada
return *this;
}
```

Comment: You _really_ don't want to do this for `operator+` - that would modify the left-hand argument in expressions like `a = b + c`. This is _not_ what one would expect :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can return an *object* from its own function in order to chain functions together:

```
#include <iostream>
class foo
{
    public:
        foo() {num = 0;}
        // Returning a `foo` creates a new copy of the object each time...
        // So returning a `foo&` returns a *reference* to this, and operates on
        // the *same* object each time.
        foo& Add(int n)  
        {
            num += n;
            std::cout << num << std::endl;
            // If you actually DO need a pointer, 
            // change the return type and do not dereference `this`
            return *this;  
        }
    private:
        int num;
};

int main()
{
    foo f;
    f.Add(10).Add(5).Add(3);
    return 0;
}
```

Which outputs:

```
$ ./a.out
10
15
18
```

Comment: @jmucchiello: This works *differently* if the return type is `foo&`. So it is not a matter of "better", it is a matter of what you really need.

Comment: @AndreyT: You're correct, I did have `foo&` in the code that I tested.  Duh!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace::std;

class Print
{
    public:
        Print * hello();
        Print * goodbye();
        Print * newLine();
};

Print * Print::hello()
{
    cout << "Hello";
    return this;
}
Print * Print::goodbye()
{
    cout << "Goodbye";
    return this;
}
Print * Print::newLine()
{
    cout << endl;
    return this;
}

int main (void)
{
    Print print;
    print.hello()->newLine()->goodbye()->newLine();

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
   Hello
   Goodbye
```